# How to automaticaly switch to HDMI audio when connected?

Tags: debian, audio, kde, hdmi

I need to make laptop running Debian 11 with KDE automatically switch from speakers to HDMI sound output (Digital Stereo (HDMI) output) when HDMI cable connects, and back to speakers when HDMI disconnects.
How can I do that?